# How to force load kernel module (modprobe -f) on startup?

Tags: debian, systemd, kernel-modules

I would like to load a custom kernel module upon startup on my system (Debian 9). The vermagic string of this module does not exactly match my kernel version, but I can load it using `modprobe -f module_name` or `insmod -f /path/to/module` and it seems to work fine.

If I just add the name of the module to `/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf` it does not work, systemctl shows that systemd-modules-load.service gets an error upon trying to load the module.

Can I tell systemd to force load the module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to override the install behaviour using a configuration file in `/etc/modprobe.d`, for example `/etc/modprobe.d/module_name.conf`:

```
install module_name /sbin/modprobe -i -f module_name
```

This instructs the module loading code to run `/sbin/modprobe -i -f module_name` when a request is made to install `module_name`. `-i` tells `modprobe` to ignore `install` directives when processing the command (otherwise we’d end up with a loop).

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the steps:

1. Add module_name.conf to /etc/modules-load.d/. 
   The module_name.conf file should simply contain a list of kernel module names to load,separated by newlines.
2. Add another module_name.conf to /etc/modprobe.d/ . 
   The content of the  file is :

   install module_name /sbin/modprobe -i -f module_name

   Tell the module loading code to run /sbin/modprobe -i -f module_name when a request is made to install module_name.
3. Add the module_name.ko to /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/

   You can put your custom kernel module file to the /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/xxx/ .
4. sudo depmod -a

   Thoroughly probes and examines all of the modules in the kernel.
5. Reboot
6. lsmod | grep module_name

   You can find your custom kernel module loaded.

Comment: Please add some explanation. I'm not sure exactly *what* your instructions are saying (better formatting would help), and it would be great if you also explained "why".